# How to send an SMS type message using Processing data?

Tags: sms, processing, arduino

I have code written up in [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) that works as a serial monitor for my [Arduino Fio](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardFio).  I have a few sensors on the Fio that output a warning message when a value surpasses a threshold. How do I get warning statements sent to a phone number as a text message as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to send email to just a particular phone (i.e. your own) or a small set of phones known in advance, many carriers have an email SMS gateway. For example, to SMS the Verizon phone 304-555-1212, just send email to 3045551212@vtext.com

See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_Email_or_Web_to_SMS

Here is an example on how to send email from Processing:  http://www.shiffman.net/2007/11/13/e-mail-processing/

Comment: The example on sending an email from Processing was especially useful. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is a good place to start with this.  Your thing -> twitter.  Twitter -> SMS (or other clients).  Otherwise, it gets expensive and more complicated.